# Normal domains and powers of height one primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian normal domain, and $P$ a height 1 prime of $A$. Then the localization $A_P$ is a discrete valuation ring. Certainly $PA_P\cap A = P$. Does this also hold for higher powers of $P$? Ie, given an integer $e\ge 2$, is:
$$P^eA_P\cap A = P^e?$$
Certainly $P^e\subseteq P^eA_P\cap A$, so it suffices to show that $P^eA_P\cap A\subseteq P^e$.

I think I can prove that this is true if $P^e$ is primary, though apparently powers of prime ideals need not be primary in general...

Comment: $R=K[X,Y,Z]/(X^2-YZ)$ is a noetherian normal domain, and $p=(x,y)$ is a height one prime whose square is not primary, so $p^2\ne p^{(2)}$.

Comment: @user26857 How do you see that it's normal?

Comment: There are few ways to show this, and [here](http://planetmath.org/sites/default/files/texpdf/39311.pdf) you can find a full proof. (One can also use the Serre's normality criterion for a short proof.)